# how to override the cache control setting of httpd.conf from the page

Tags: apache, caching, http-headers, coldfusion-9

We have the "cache-control" setting as "public" in httpd.conf

```
Header set Cache-Control "public"
```

But from the page we are trying to not cache it, hence we are setting the header as

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<cfheader name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate">
```

But we found that, it always takes the cache-control setting from httpd.conf
Is there any way to override the header setting in httpd.conf from page level.

Note: "cfheader" is a ColdFusion tag to generates custom HTTP response headers to return to the client.

Comment: I don't think you can override that. You can't edit the httpd.conf?

Comment: yes we are able to edit that, but not sure how to proceed, if we want to cache some of the html pages and don't want to cache other html pages.

Comment: There are many options. Try (if your apache is 2.4.7 or later) `Header setifempty Cache-Control "public"`

Comment: We have apache 2.2.3 . Is there any way for it?

Comment: I think the proper way would be to remove `Header Set` from apache conf and set `Cache-Control public` from page where needed. Or if you can provide a rule based on file extension, for example "for .css .js .png set public, for all others use page setting", we could make that work.

Comment: I found that if we will use the "early" mode of processing in the httpd.conf then if any header comes from the page content then those will override the settings on httpd.conf,                                                 

`Header set Cache-Control "public" early`

But why is it advised to use for debugging/testing purpose? Is there any issue if we use this in live server?

Comment: Sorry, that is beyond my knowledge.